# Is there any scope of improvement in my query to make it run faster?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to writing queries and wanted to know if the execution of the query can be made faster

```
 select 
p.attr_value product,
m.attr_value model,
u.attr_value usage,
t4.attr_value location
       from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.e_subid = t2.e_subid
                      join table4 t4 on t4.loc_id = t1.loc_id
                      join table3 p  on t2.e_cid = p.e_cid 
                      join table3 m  on t2.e_cid = m.e_cid 
                      join table3 u  on t2.e_cid = u.e_cid 
 Where
          t4.attr_name = 'Location' 
          and p.attr_name  = 'Product'
          and m.attr_name  = 'Model'
          and u.attr_name  = 'Usage'
          order by product,location;
```

Comment: It is impossible to help you without having at least the execution plan.

Comment: @zaratustra I didn't understand...what do you mean by execution plan?

Comment: Regarding the execution plan. Please read the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9010.htm#SQLRF01601 you also need to provide the definition of all tables and all defined indexes. See also here: http://tkyte.blogspot.de/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html

Comment: How do you suppose to improve the performance with no knowledge about it? There is not a silver bullet that fix any performance for any query. You have to know at least what statistics is and how it is used, also you have to know how to create a execution plan and be able to read it.

Comment: @zaratustra Appreciate your comment.

Comment: So far I can offer you to check if you have indexes for all the foreign keys you have. Each foreign key has to be with an index, it helps you, at least, to avoid deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

A brute force method to improve performance is to create index the columns are used in joins, where clause and order by

In your case create indexes on the below columns

- table4.attr_name *(used in where clause)*
- table3.attr_name *(used in where clause)*
- table1.e_subid *(used in join clause)*
- table2.e_subid *(used in join clause)*
- table4.loc_id *(used in join clause)*

Note that indexes will help you with faster select query performance. But slows down update, insert and delete statements

See if oracle materialized views can fit your needs

The alias 'l' you used in projection, is not defined in your query. You might want to check it